# Can you use glob syntax inside of packages with meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have a package in meteor that gets a little tedious to add all the bits.

```
api.addFiles([
  'client/blah.jade',
  'client/blah.js',
  'client/blah.scss',
  // etc...
]);
```

By chance, does there exist a way to use glob syntax in order to add files to the api? For example:

```
api.addFiles('client/**/(*.js|*.jade|*.scss)');
```

I know [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) exists, but can this be used within a package?

Answer (score 3):

`api.addFiles` does not support glob syntax, but you can use glob npm package:

```
Npm.depends({
  glob: '6.0.1'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  var globSync = Npm.require('glob').sync;

  api.addFiles(globSync('client/**/(*.js|*.jade|*.scss)'));
});
```

Comment: globSync return a empty array :(

Comment: Juan, did you add the node-globe package with meteor npm?